# Java - close multi-layer stream wrapper

Tags: java, stream

In Java, we usually use a stream object to wrap another stream class for efficiency. For example:

```
Object obj = new MyClass();
try {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("test.txt");
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

   oos.writeObject(obj);
   oos.flush();
} catch(IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    fos.close();
    oos.close();
}
```

I use `ObjectOutputStream` to wrap `FileOutputStream`. A similar case is using `BufferedReader` to wrap `InputStreamReader`.

My question is how to close the `fos` and `oos` properly in order. Which one should be closed first? Or just need to close either one.
Usually closing both streams will work, but I feel uncomfortable with this way since I don't understand the semantics. I just use the close method to close everything, while I don't know why not just close `fos` or `oos`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Closing the wrapper stream automatically closes the inner stream.*

So, in your case you only need to close `ObjectOutputStream`. Closing a stream twice does not throw an exception hence what you've already been doing (although unnecessary) works as well.

Here's what happens when you instantiate an `ObjectOutputStream`

```
public ObjectOutputStream(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    bout = new BlockDataOutputStream(out); // inner stream being wrapped
    ...
}
```

Here's the implementation of `ObjectOutputStream.close()`

```
public void close() throws IOException {
    flush();
    clear();
    bout.close(); // inner stream being closed
}
```